# SmartDraw 2010: How to easily align 2 objects?

Tags: smartdraw

I have not found any easier way than manually checking the "top" position of one object and then again manually opening the properties of the targes object and setting there the same "top" position. Isn't there any easier way? System is windows 7 64 bits

Answer (score 0):

From the help for [Aligning, Rotating, and Grouping](http://www.smartdraw.com/product/features/aligning-rotating-grouping/)

[image]

Comment: yes but that is not working, for example when I've objects with different sizes